# Android error : I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 16.159MB for 1490086-byte

Tags: android, heap-memory

I'm composing a JSON file with objects in a for loop
When the number of data transferred to the JSON file increases, I see the following error in the Logcat:

> I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 16.159MB for 1490086-byte
>   allocation

What is wrong here ?
I've verified some other posts on `Grow heap (frag case)` but no result!
What's increasing the heap size which results in such an error?

Loop code:

```
JSON_Functions_PRD mJSONF_Test = new JSON_Functions_PRD();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
String Temp;
Temp = obj.toString();
mJSONF_Test.setJSONobj_PRD(Temp);
mJSONF_Test.CreateMenu_SMS_Naked();

A_DataClass m_DataClass = new A_DataClass();
int count = 10000;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    mDataClass.setA("A1");
    mDataClass.setB("B1");
    mJSONF_Test.setItem_M0(mDataClass);
}
```

JSON functions:

```
public class JSON_Functions_PRD {

String mJSONString_Result;
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

public void setJSONobj_PRD(String mJSONString) {
    try {
        mJSONString_Result = mJSONString;
        obj = new JSONObject(mJSONString_Result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getJSON_PRD() {

    mJSONString_Result = obj.toString();
    return mJSONString_Result;
}

public void CreateMenu_SMS_Naked() {
    JSONArray jA1 = new JSONArray();
    try {
        obj.put("M0", jA1);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void setItem_M0(A_DataClass Item) {
    JSONArray jA1 = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jO1 = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject jO2 = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jA1 = obj.getJSONArray("M0");

        jO1.put("a", Item.getA());
        jO2.put("a", Item.getB());
        jO1.put("b", jO2);
        jA1.put(jO1);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Dataclass:

```
public class A_DataClass {
    String A;
    String B;

    public A_DataClass()
    {
    }

    public String getA() {
        return A;
    }
    public void setA(String name) {
        thisA = name;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return B;
    }
    public void setB(String name) {
        this.B = name;
    }
}
```

Edit:
I should add this point that I tested the case on 3 mobile sets (2 SAMSUNG's, 1 HUAWEI) and the problem is seen just in HUAWEI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heap may have a lot of memory available, but fragmented in small chunks. If the VM cannot find a chunk big enough for the allocation are you trying to do, an OOME will happen.